# STS/Eclipse egit started failing after update

Tags: eclipse, egit, spring-tool-suite

I got update notification from Sprint Tool Suite or STS. I updated the packages as it asked for and did not pay attention to what exactly got updated. After the update, remote git operations i.e. push/pull are failing with following error. Git integration was working fine before the update and git commands do work properly from command line. STS still shows repository name and does recognize that project is connected to git

> Can't connect to any repository: user@server:repository
>   (user@server:repository: connection failed)

I see following error getting logged in .log file of the workspace

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
>   user@server:repository: connection failed     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:180)   at
>   org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java:215)    at
>   org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushJob.performJob(PushJob.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.jobs.RepositoryJob.run(RepositoryJob.java:57)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
>   by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:
>   user@server:repository: connection failed     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.(JschSession.java:156)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession.exec(JschSession.java:92)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshPushConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openPush(TransportGitSsh.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:160)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1310)   at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:169)   ... 4
>   more

Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.9.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201710111144
Platform: Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Comment: This looks like [Eclipse bug 513043](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513043) which has already been fixed. Does updating JGit/EGit to 4.9 (update site: `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`) fix your problem?

Comment: @howlger, This issue looks different than my problem. I am not getting any complaints from eclipse/STS about authorization or at least nothing is getting logged.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem since the updates, but running on Eclipse Oxygen 1a.

I've created an issue with Spring Ide.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/210

Comment: I appreciate you reported this to the Spring IDE, but it looks like [Eclipse bug 513043](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513043) which has already been fixed (but not in Oxygen.1a). Does updating JGit/EGit to 4.9 (via the update site: `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`) fix your problem?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not fix my problem. Still the same errormessage. Which is also different than in the bug report you linked

Comment: I see. Good job to report it to STS! So downgrading STS can be used as workaround until the bug is fixed?